# Why is idle cloud SQL instance showing 10 qps write requests?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have connected an appmaker app to a 2nd generation MySQL instance on gcp.

ALl seems to work fine, but I noticed that cloud console believes this instance sees 10 write ops per second at all times, even when nothing should be running.

The SQL logs seems to say that there are no requests. Billing does not look off, so I'm just wondering if I see something like prober requests, although 10QPS is a bit high for that, and I would expect to see something in the logs.

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

**Update**: Looks like any gcp MySQL instance has a heartbeat every 2 seconds, or every second if automatic backups are enabled.

These heartbeats seem pretty cheap in terms of CPU utilization, but they seem to make storage grow slowly over time.

I'm still interested to know if the heartbeat frequency can be tuned lower (for non-replicated setups; replication heartbeat frequency can be tuned.)

Comment: I suspect the metric you are looking at is not instantaneous metric, but an average or a peak over a period of time. There should be some information available about what that metric is supposed to be showing. As far as the SQL log, we would typically need to (temporarily) enable general_log to get all of the activity recorded. If general_log is disabled, that would explain why we aren't seeing any MySQL activity recorded in the log.

Comment: I don't think there is averaging going on I see a solid 10QPS write ops/sec over a 24h period, with occasional spikes on top of that. If I enable general log, I see addtl 5QPS and errors like those:

---
 insertId:  "1#966174330594#3874586074080570734#general#1536956686657130505#114927-0@a3"  
 logName:  "projects/xxx/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-general.log"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-xxxx 
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type:  "cloudsql_database"   
 }
 textPayload:  "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE master_time=UTC_TIMESTAMP(6)"  
 timestamp:  "2018-xxx"  
}---

Comment: Maybe more interesting,  see these repeated requests in the log, roughly one per second:

    A  2018-09-14T20:24:37.149559Z 56092 Query INSERT INTO mysql.heartbeat(id, master_time) 
    A  VALUE(1, UTC_TIMESTAMP(6)) 
    A  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE master_time=UTC_TIMESTAMP(6) 
    A  2018-09-14T20:24:38.154699Z 56092 Query INSERT INTO mysql.heartbeat(id, master_time) 
    A  VALUE(1, UTC_TIMESTAMP(6)) 
    A  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE master_time=UTC_TIMESTAMP(6)

Unclear who is sending these many heartbeats or why. Maybe that is working as intended ?